# How to match a simple number pattern in VBA using RegEx

Tags: regex, vba

How do I check if a string is either a one digit number OR a two digit number and otherwise return `false`?

Comment: You can do this with VBA LIKE: Bool=Digits like "#" or Digits like "##"

Comment: @charles can u put that in an answer please

Comment: Anyone having trouble with regular expressions, I found this tool to be very useful. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Here is another helpful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/2521) to Regex specific to Excel, with examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
Function OneOrTwo(i As Integer) As Boolean
Dim objRegEx As Object
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Global = True

objRegEx.Pattern = "^\d{1,2}$"

OneOrTwo = objRegEx.Test(i)
End Function
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Comment: +1 although the `IgnoreCase` and `Global` lines are redundant for checking a numeric string.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this using VBA LIKE:

```
Function OneOrTwo(Digits As Variant) As Boolean
    OneOrTwo = Digits Like "#" Or Digits Like "##"
End Function
```

Comment: +1 for not requiring extra reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF CInt(myNumberString) < 100 Then
    MsgBox "String must be either 1 or 2 digits"
Else
    Msgbox "Failed"
End IF
```

Should work for you.

Comment: Sorry, noticed you asked for regex..

Answer (score 1):

Remou had it right. Here is a RegexContains function so you can use it with all sorts of patterns, not just the one you need now.

```
Function RegexContains(ByVal find_in As String, _
                       ByVal find_what As String, _
                       Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False) As Boolean

Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = find_what
RE.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
RE.Global = True
RegexContains = RE.Test(find_in)

End Function
```

Following the example from Remou, assuming the cell is A1, you'd write:

=RegexContains(A1, "^\d{1,2}$")

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would try. /d for digit, ? for option 2 digits.

/d/d?

or

/d{1,2}