# Test string format

Tags: excel, vba

How can I test whether a string is in the format beginning with "R", followed by up to 8 numbers?

Comment: That is a very broad question with very limited context. Try giving a bit more details of you issue and what you've tried so far ? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops/22542835#22542835) could be a way of solving your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I want to trigger a certain action when a cell is activated, but only if it contains a string in a certain format. I was going to use `InStr` but I am not sure how to adapt it.

Comment: Test character by character; use the `Like` operator; regular expressions.  There are all kinds of methods of testing.

Comment: Let say you want at least 1 number after the "R", you can test it with: `debug.print test_string like "R#*" and len(test_string) <10`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match a simple number pattern in VBA using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4809453/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily accomplished using Regular Expressions.

```
Function testString(ByVal tstStr As String) As Boolean

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "^R\d{0,8}$"
        .IgnoreCase = False
        testString = .test(tstStr)
    End With

End Function
```

`.test()` returns a Boolean value if `tstStr` matches your `.Pattern`.

Breaking down the pattern `^R\d{0,8}$`

- `^` Start of string
- `R` matches a literal R

  - If you are okay with also matching a lowercase `r`, then you can set `IgnoreCase = True`
- `\d` matches a digit 0-8 times `{0,8}`
- `$` matches the end of string

Since this is a function, you can test any input string

```
Debug.Print testString("R123456")
Rem: Prints 'True'
```

Comment: Thank you. Since I will only use this once, can I take it out of the function and test against ActiveCell.Value?

Comment: I am a firm believer that specialized code should be self contained. Of course, you can do this by doing `= .test(ActiveCell.Value)` if you choose to do so. If you keep it a function, you can use `testString(ActiveCell.value)` as well.

Comment: It will be quicker doing that. If you were compiling with speed optimisations enabled it would make the function inline.

Answer (score 1):

See https://theburningmonk.com/2012/05/performance-test-string-contains-vs-string-indexof-vs-regex-ismatch/ on why RegEx is not the best choice for simple tasks.

```
Str = "R12345678"
If Left(Str,1) = "R" then 
    if IsNumeric(Mid(Str, 2)) then 
        MsgBox "Match"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I would add `And len(Str) <= 9` before the 2nd then to completely cover the OP's question.